# Getting to Horseshoe Bend, Arizona?

Tags: transportation, arizona

I'm interested in getting to [Horseshoe Bend, Arizona](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horseshoe_Bend_%28Arizona%29) later this month, on the cheap, from Vancouver.  How best to do this?

[Map is here](http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Page,+AZ,+United+States&hl=en&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=54.665451,54.404297&oq=Page+A&hnear=Page,+Coconino,+Arizona&t=m&z=12)

The [only Wikitravel page I can find](http://wikitravel.org/en/Page#The_Horseshoe_Bend) is on the [town of Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page,_Arizona), which is nearby, and mentions it, but not how to get there.

I'm happy to fly, bus or drive.

Comment: It may help to look at the right part of Arizona on the map. Page has an [airport](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_Municipal_Airport), not that [they](http://visitpagearizona.com/discover/getting-to-page-lake-powell.html) advertise it.

Comment: That's a neat area to visit.  I took a trip there a few years ago, and in addition to Horseshoe Bend I visited Zion National Park, the Glen Canyon Dam, and Antelope Canyon (Google all of them).

Comment: good grief, I have no idea how I had the original location.  Thank goodness Wiki was right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did some research on that area a year or two back when I first heard about Horseshoe Bend, although I haven't managed to make it there yet!

The only airport that is remotely close is in Page, AZ. Great Lakes Aviation has a number of flights there, both under their own name as well as under United codeshares.  Frontier also have a small number of flights from Denver.  Prices vary significantly, but if you book a bit in advance it looks like sub-C$300 is possible from YVR which is a pretty good price!

Other options would include flying into Las Vegas (often good prices, and cheap car rental!), Flagstaff or even Phoenix and driving, although it's not a short drive!

If you've got some time to spare, I'd suggest flying into Las Vegas and driving north to the Zion National Park area, such as somewhere like Hurricane.  You can then spend time in both the Page area, as well as Zion which is an amazing place!

Comment: Salt Lake City is also a manageable distance.

Comment: Google Maps puts SLC at close to 400 miles, compared to less than 300 for both LAS and PHX.  I suppose it depends on your definition of "manageable" :)  In my experience (and this obviously depends on where you're coming from) flights into SLC always seem to cost more than LAS or PHX too.

Comment: Sub-300 maybe in the future, but for the weekend of May 20th, not so much :/